# How can find Subdocuments using $where in MongoDb

Tags: php, mongodb

Collection contains data like this

```
    {
        '_id': ObjectId("527cf8ae3ad5a461caf925fc"),
        'name': {
            'first': 'John',
            'last': 'Backus'
        }
    }
```

I want find record where first name 'John' through $where

```
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB('school');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'student');
    $js = "function() {
        return this.first.name == 'John';
    }";
    $cursor = $collection->find(array('$where' => $js));
```

I am getting exception 
    Caught exception: localhost:27017: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined near 'this.name.first=='Jo'

I would like to search only with $where.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: @NanheKumar i have already read this link but here no example like this

Comment: why do you want to use $where in this scenario?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky : Because this is fit for requirement condition.

Comment: @ParnitDas sorry, I don't know what that means.  What is the requirement condition?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really weird scenario. Why would you do this if you can find it with

```
db.collection.find({'name.first' : 'John'})
```

Anyway, the error is in the `first.name` and your collection has a schema `name.first`

```
$js = "function() {
    return this.name.first == 'John';
}";
```

Basically it is trying to tell you that "I am looking into the field name and it is undefined and then when I am checking for a field first of this undefined I crashed".

Comment: @Salvandor this is possible or not through $where because i know how can find other using approach

Comment: Did not get you. I just showed you where was your error and showed you how to fix it.

Comment: It is really hard to understand what are you typing... Look at my code properly and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
   $m = new MongoClient();
   $db = $m->school;
   $collection = $db->student;
   $cursor = $collection->find( array('name.first' => 'John' ));

   foreach ($cursor as $document) {
      var_dump($document);
   }
```